Nontrivial nonrandom properties of prime numbers
What are some nontrivial nonrandom properties of prime numbers. Consider the simple model where each number is prime with probability 1/log(n) by Montgomery and extensions of it.  Once you add some simple modulo constraints it seems to capture very accurately many of the key properties, such as twin primes, linear sequences of primes, largest distance between primes and as far as I know most of the statistical properties of distances between primes.  Are there any significant properties that it does not capture that are nontrivial and not easily explained by standard heuristics and we still don't understand.

Discussed in detail by Terence Tao here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/254a-supplement-4-probabilistic-models-and-heuristics-for-the-primes-optional/ Also Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture

@QiaochuYuan maybe even better to directly link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maier%27s_theorem

A near-example is https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720 (but, as explained in that paper, the unusual regularity is ultimately explainable by "standard heuristics").

@TerryTao  Thanks, that was one of the papers that motivated my question.

@QiaochuYuan thanks, I should go back and reread it but Tao's blog post and Maynard's IAS lecture on YouTube was what got me thinking about this, since these random models and simple heuristics seem to capture almost everything. I'm interested in what they don't capture.

@TerryTao I forgot to add in my previous response about the biases paper that I thought that the biases disappear asymptotically so these are just larger finite error terms than one might expect.

One may have more examples if one looks at other areas of analytic number theory than the primes, such as the statistics of ranks of elliptic curves, where strong heuristic foundations are much more recent (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01431, as well as the more recent work on murmurations)
